# How do I use accepts_nested_attributes_for and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I have a trouble with `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in Rails.

I have two models, User and UserCart:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_cart
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_cart
```

and:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
```

When a user signs up, he creates the user cart too.

This is my view:

```
= form_for @user, as: :user, url: users_path, html: { class: 'forms forms-columnar' } do |f|
  p
    = f.label :email
    = f.email_field :email, class: 'width-100'
  .user_cart
    = f.fields_for :user_cart do |user_cart_field|
      p
        = user_cart_field.label :inn
        = user_cart_field.text_field :inn
```

Why do I need to use this long and bad code to make `user_cart` fields fill-in after clicking the "Save" button, instead of a simple `@user = User.new(permitted_params)`?

```
@user = User.new
@user.build_user_cart
@user.assign_attributes(permitted_params)
```

Comment: Which code are you referring to when you say "long and bad code"?  Can you also post your `new` and `create` controller actions and explain what's not working.

Comment: @vee, explained, see last lines

Comment: I assume you don't actually have two user models and you mistakenly posted your user cart model as user?

Comment: Philip, this is just a simplificated overview above.

Answer (score 1):

Your user model should be:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :user_cart
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_cart

class UserCart < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
```

Your belongs_to/has_one relationship was incorrectly setup.

Comment: You meant to write that a user has_one User?

Comment: One UserCart has_one User.

UserCart is main.